# I tried install vim and wget in dockerfile but i'm getting an error

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops

```
[root@ip-172-31-81-59 manojapp]# docker build -t manoj-app .
[+] Building 1.7s (5/6)                                                                                                                                  docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 164B                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                   0.3s
 => CACHED [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:e9569c25505f33ff72e88b2990887c9dcf230f23259da296eb814fc2b41af999                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [2/3] RUN apt-get install wget -y                                                                                                                        1.2s
------                                                                                                                                                                  
 > [2/3] RUN apt-get install wget -y:
1.152 Reading package lists...
1.179 Building dependency tree...
1.181 Reading state information...
1.182 E: Unable to locate package wget
------

Dockerfile:2

--------------------
   1 |     FROM ubuntu
   2 | >>> RUN apt-get install wget -y
   3 |     RUN apt-get install vim -y
   4 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install wget -y" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

please help me to fix this error

Comment: (The application you're running in the container probably uses normal file APIs to edit files, and the application doesn't invoke `vim`, so you probably don't need to install it in a normal single-process container.  APT/dpkg have some significant overhead and you might find it faster to run `apt-get install` only once with multiple packages.)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message:

> 1.182 E: Unable to locate package wget

You have to call `RUN apt-get update` first to read the list of available packages

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN apt-get install vim -y
```

output of `docker build`:

```
[+] Building 1.1s (8/8) FINISHED                                                                                                 docker:default
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 135B                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                           1.0s
 => [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu@sha256:e9569c25505f33ff72e88b2990887c9dcf230f23259da296eb814fc2b41af999                            0.0s
 => CACHED [2/4] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                        0.0s
 => CACHED [3/4] RUN apt-get install wget -y                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [4/4] RUN apt-get install vim -y                                                                                                0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:157755c56ff53ad8a61ab3c2a90cd1c746c336a46cf786c144f84f9f9efbc5fe

                                           0.0s
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: I have tried it by my own and it worked fine. Do you get a different message?